# Change node Value of last Child

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

I have this xml file, and I try to change nodeValue for the last node, but not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<files>
 <file>.DS_Store</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_1.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_12.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_15.xml</file>
</files>
```

I found the node this:

```
$Sig = new DomDocument();
$Sig->loadXML($xml);
$dom = $Sig->documentElement;

$Node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('file')->item(0);
$Node->lastChild->nodeValue = 'ID2PDF_log_17.xml'; // <-- Not working
```

Why not working?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly fine. It sets the last node of the first item with TagName 'file' to  'ID2PDF_log_17.xml' But you don't need `$dom = $Sig->documentElement;`. And change `$dom` to `$Sig`

```
$Sig = new DomDocument();
$Sig->loadXML($xml);
$dom = $Sig->documentElement; // ← delete

//--------↓ change to $Sig
$Node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('file')->item(0);
$Node->lastChild->nodeValue = 'ID2PDF_log_17.xml';
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<files>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_17.xml</file> //← changed
 <file>ID2PDF_log_1.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_12.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_15.xml</file>
</files>
```

---

In your question I understand you want to change the last nodeValue. So if you want to change the last nodeValue instead of the first node which you are currently changing, just change the item counter to 3 (counter starts at 0)

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<files>
 <file>.DS_Store</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_1.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_12.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_15.xml</file>
</files>';

$Sig = new DomDocument();
$Sig->loadXML($xml);

//-----------------------------------------------↓
$Node = $Sig->getElementsByTagName('file')->item(3);
$Node->lastChild->nodeValue = 'ID2PDF_log_17.xml'; // <-- Not working

echo $Sig->saveXML();
?>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<files>
 <file>.DS_Store</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_1.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_12.xml</file>
 <file>ID2PDF_log_17.xml</file> //← changed
</files>
```